# What does "assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets" mean at all?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Having started learning Java, I came across this statement in the docs of Java 8:

*assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.*

Does that simply mean that the order you get, after assigning, will be a mess?

Comment: Yes, the messier the better! Imagine you have 1000 values having 500 different hash codes. Those 500 hash codes maybe put in 100 buckets reserved momentarily. Per average 5 conflicting hashcodes in a bucket, 10 conflictimg values. Reading from `HashMap` will be out of order. `TreeMap` (not a hash map), will be a `SortedMap`, And `LinkedHashMap` will keep a List to maintain be order of _insertion_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that HashMap maintains an **array** of *buckets* under the hood. **Hash code** produced by the `hashCode()` method of a *key* object determines to which *bucket* this entry should go.

A situation when multiple *keys* yield *similar hashes* and as a consequence are mapped to the same *bucket* is called a **collision**.

Entries of the map that are mapped to the same *bucket* will be structured as a *linked list*. Starting with *Java 8* when a number of collisions grow after a certain threshold the list will be transformed into a *tree*.

As you probably know the cost of accessing an element under a certain index in the array is **O(1)**. And HashMap provides access to the values by key with amortized time complexity **O(1)**, but only if a number of collisions is neglectable. I.e. `hashCode()` is implemented in such a way that it allows to spread the keys relatively evenly between the buckets.

In the edge case when the **hash function** is badly implemented and, let's say, it returns the *same **hash** for every key* all the entries end up in the *same bucket*. The time complexity for methods like `get()`, `containsKey()` degrades to **O(n)** (with *Java 7* and earlier) because you have to iterate over the *list* of all entries in order to find a particular one. And with *Java 8* onwards the time complexity will be **O(log n)** because that is the worse time required to find an element in a *red-black tree*.

> Does that simply mean that the **order** you get, after assigning, will be
> a mess?

The order of elements in the `HashMap` is undefined. This class is useful when you need quick access and don't care about the order. If need an ordered map consider `LinkedHashMap` which tracks the order in which the entries were added to a map by maintaining a linked list or `TreeMap` which sorts keys ordered accordingly to their natural order or based on the given comparator.

Answer (score 0):

A hash map contains a number of "buckets".  For best performance, you want the number of entries to be more or less the same in each bucket.  The bucket is determined by the hash function; thus you want a hash function that results in more or less the same probability of hitting each bucket.  That is, "the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets".

At the other extreme: a hash function that always returned, say, the value 3 would work, but map access wouldn't be very efficient, since one bucket would have all the entries.

I don't understand what you mean by the order being a "mess".  A hash map is not ordered; the location of an element depends on its hash code.